# can not converting word with y as vowel words (ie gym) in pig latin translator

Tags: python

I am starting out with programming, teaching myself Python 3.4.3.  I have a question with regards to a pig Latin translator (seems to be everybody's favorite program to write, and ask questions for).

My code seems to work fine, except when I write a word that has y as the only vowel in it.

```
def pig_latin(word):
    print(word)#test
    if word[0] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
        i = 0
        print(word[i]) #test
        while word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
            i += 1
        word = word[i:] + word[:i] + 'ay'
    elif word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word += 'way'
    return word

def main():
    sentence = input('Enter a phrase to convert to pig latin: ')
    word = ''
    pig_sentence = ''
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        if sentence[i] != ' ':
            word += sentence[i]
        else:
            pig_sentence += pig_latin(word) + ' '
            word = ''
    pig_sentence += pig_latin(word)
    print(pig_sentence)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I receive is with regards to this line of code:

```
while word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
```

and the error reads: IndexError: string index out of range

After playing with a lot of stuff, I am a bit stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Practice with the word "gym."  word[0] is g, so while g is in that list of letters (it is), set i=1.  word[1] is y, so while y is in the list (it is), set i=2.  word [2] is m, so while m is in the list of letters (it is), set i = 3.  Uh-oh, there is no word[3].  Out of range!

Comment: Thank you, go it now.  I added the statement: and i < len(word) - 1 to my while loop.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @J Kelly - You should write a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an element of your `word` that doesn't exist whenever that loop runs out of letters before it finds a proper vowel.

Try this:

```
while i < len(word) and word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when there are no vowels in the word. If there are no vowels the following `while` loop never stops and you get an IndexError:

```
while word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
    i += 1
word = word[i:] + word[:i] + 'ay'
```

To fix this, check that i is less than the length of the word:

```
while i < len(word) and word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
    i += 1
word = word[i:] + word[:i] + 'ay'
```

Now with this implementation, the first character does not get moved to the end of the word (i.e. gym turns into gymay), so write a condition for that:

```
while i < len(word) and word[i] in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
    i += 1
if i == len(word): 
    i = 1
word = word[i:] + word[:i] + 'ay'
```

Comment: Thanks, Much appreciated!